# VB6: Print # Statement

Tags: vb6

How do I print the following string "General Unit Information not specific to report date:" in bold.

```
Print #FileNumber, Margin & "General Unit Information not specific to report date:"
```

#FileNumber is defined as `Open FileName For Output As #FileNumber` where FileName is a location for a File and Margin is a String of set empty spaces.

Any ideas?

Comment: How to get the string "General Unit Information not specific to report date:" to print in bold text

Comment: Print in VB only outputs raw text to what will end up being a flat text file, so no bold possible. You will need to generate a file of another format either Word (.doc/.docx), RTF, PDF, etc.

Comment: @Francis Thanks, I had found this on the web as well but didn't know if there was a way around it. Sadly this means hours of tearing out old code :(

Comment: Should not be too hard, there are myriad 3rd party libraries out there to help you out depending on the format you choose. Fred's answer seems a good start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do it in plain text file but this is what worked for me.

Open file

```
Print #FileNumber, "{\rtf"
Print #FileNumber, Margin & "\b General Unit Information not specific to report date:\b"
Print #FileNumber, "}"
```

Save file as `Filename.RTF`

Opens in Wordpad